# How would I find the general term $a_n$ for this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Problem**:
>   Find the formula for $n^{th}$ term of the sequence $-1, 0, 2, 6, 14, 30 \ldots$

I identified that the difference is the double of the previous
i.e 1, 2, 4, 8, 16

How would I use this to find the formula if I was to asked to find the $50^{th}$ or even the $100^{th}$ term?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: calculate the difference between $1,2,4,8,16,\ldots$ and the terms of your sequence.

Comment: This is simply $2^n-2$ starting from $0$. So the 50th term is $2^{50}-2$

Comment: Wrong, in my oppinion the sequence is $-1, 0, 2, 6, 14, 30$ and all further terms are $2019$. It is **important** to disqualify such questions, which are not of mathematical nature.

Comment: "It is important to disqualify such questions, which are not of mathematical nature." -- Matter of opinion. If there is a clear, underlying mathematical pattern that can be logically deduced, then as far as **I** care, it's of a mathematical nature. To blindly say all "continue the sequence" problems are inherently nonmathematical is more of a smart-aleck response than anything, because most such sequences **are** defined with an inherent, mathematical pattern in mind. I'd argue your focus should be on the obviously **poorly-formed** problems, rather than the type of problem altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments the $n$th term is
$$a_n=2^n-2=2(2^{n-1}-1)$$

Edit: one can also conclude that the sequence follows any pattern the user desires with adequate reasoning, so this question therefore cannot have a 'correct' answer without being supplied with infinite terms of the series.

Comment: The first part of this answer is not based on Mathematical reasoning. In my opinion such questions should not be answered on this site. Even specification of $a_n$ for infinitely many $n$ is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

[Numberphile - Strong law of small numbers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UgZ5FqdYIQ&app=desktop)

Shows, you can come up with any assumption about a sequence, to base your prediction on. I know that sequence of differences (in an attempt to get a polynomial prediction in my math classes growing up) is taught in school, but it can be misleading. Your repeated sequence of differences, are consistently powers of 2 . This means $2^n-2$ starting at n=0, equally validly, $\frac{M_{n+1}-M_n}{2}-2$ at n=1 etc. all describe this start sequence. That's why, if you attempt to do this on a more serious math forum, you are possibly likely to get laughed at etc. start index, is as important as the values, when coming up with serious relations.